# How to return System Locale rather than User Locale?

Tags: vb6, locale, regional-settings

I'm running a VB6.0 application and testing whether changing locale settings causes errors. The application works fine when both User Locale and system locale are set to the same country. However if the User Locale is different from the system locale then I have problems.

Why is GetThreadLocale not returning the system locale?

It appears to return the User Locale.

E.g.

System locale is set to Polish and User Locale (UK), GetThreadLocale returns 2057. Why is 1045 not being returned?

Any tips or advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

VB6 is unicode internally and with COM. API calls, which includes any windows created by forms, is ANSI.

VB6's help has a big chapter on this topic.

For ANSI applications you set the non unicode setting in Regional Options.

Windows created with CreateWindowExA have all unicode strings sent to them converted to ANSI and vice versa for CreateWindowsExW (W means Wide, ie two bytes per character).

This is because Windows 95 didn't support unicode.

Comment: I might be wrong, but your answer seems to be a little off topic. Could you be more precise about OP's question?

Comment: His threads are marked ANSI. I told him to fix system settings. Before Windows fixed programs I pointed out there is a whole chapter in Help of all the different approaches. But Windows now fixes it if set correctly.